# How do I get the address to kernel modules nt and win32k?

Tags: windows, windows-server-2008, windbg, etw, windows-kernel

I need to know the base addresses where nt and win32k are loaded.  I can find out this information by booting the system with kernel debugging enabled, start a kernel debug session, and run the command `lm` to get a list of the loaded modules.

What I want to do is programmatically determine where these two modules are loaded without booting into debug mode and using the kernel debugger.  I need the base addresses for resolving syscalls in an Event Tracing for Windows log file.

The system I am working on is running Windows Server 2008 R2.

Comment: https://www.nirsoft.net/utils/driverview.html

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The list of loaded kernel modules and base addresses (including `ntoskrnl`) is stored in the list pointed by `PsLoadedModuleList` symbol.
Or use `ZwQuerySystemInformation(SystemModuleInformation)` instead.

For detailed information see http://alter.org.ua/docs/nt_kernel/procaddr/

Comment: Excellent.  Thank you for the reference.  This solution is great because it is useful for both kernel-mode and user-mode.  

Researching your answer also lead me to 2 other API calls, EnumDeviceDrivers and GetDeviceDriverBaseName that look like they accomplish the same thing.